# Sitecore jss dictionary service returns the same values

Tags: jss, dictionary

Sitecore jss dictionary service returns the same values. In one moment dictionary contained one values and after change config to get that dictionary values not from default dictionary, i get them but even if i change them I continue to get the same values.

Comment: May be the new values added are in workflow and you are trying to retrieve the values from web db.?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Database which you configured in the jss-app config which you deployed in [.\Website\App_Config\Include\JSS-APP-NAME.config]

```
            <site patch:before="site[@name='website']"
            inherits="website"
            name="portal-poc-app"
            hostName="portal-poc1.massmutual.com"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content/portal-poc-app"
            startItem="/home"
            database="**web**" />
```

If it's configured as "web" then check the new dictionary items which you created are available in the web db.

If you configured "master" and new dictionary entries which are not coming up then make sure the jss-app config is available and proper in the include folder of your Sitecore instance. [.\Website\App_Config\Include\JSS-APP-NAME.config].

To update the config to the Sitecore instance, you can use the command **jss deploy config**

Also check whether the dictionary entries are coming up properly after you update the config using http://HOSTNAME/sitecore/api/jss/dictionary/JSS-APP-NAME/en?sc_apikey={API-KEY}. This url returns the dictionary items available under the JSS-APP-NAME root path in a folder called "Dictionary".

If you still face any issues then update the Sitecore version, Application mode, Client Framework and connected or dis-connected mode etc. in the question to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was in that I created dictionary domain from template that default dictionary used "Node template", but not default dictionary must be created from Dictionary Domain template.